# Can unpermitted work cause an unrelated insurance claim to be denied?

Tags: insurance, home-insurance, florida

For example, if I install a deck on my property without a permit and then a hurricane rips my roof off, could the claim get denied?

Or if I install drywall in my garage and turn it into living space without a permit and there is an electrical fire in one of the bedrooms, could the claim get denied?

Comment: What does your policy say?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I added the FL tag.

Comment: Asking for a friend???

Answer (score 1):

> Can unpermitted work cause an unrelated insurance claim to be denied?

The issue will be determining if there is a relationship between the unpermitted work and the damages.

In some cases it will be clear they are unrelated, but in other cases the homeowner and the insurance company will disagree.

The timing of the work will also be important. If the previous owner did the work, and the current owner had no idea, then there might still be coverage. But if the current owner didn't follow the building code or tried to cut corners, then the denial is more likely.